# Using jQuery serialize with ajax posting some input fields as arrays

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization

Hi I have the following HTML:

```
...
    <td><input type="text" name="code[]" value="" /></td>
    <td>
          <select class="selectProductOrders" name="selectProductOrders[]">
              <option value="default" disabled selected>Select a product</option> 
          </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="rsp[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="trade[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount[]" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="qty[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost[]" value="" /></td>
```

...

I am attempting to post data to the server but split the array input fields up. I have tried a lot, including the serialise method:

```
        var theForm = $('#transferOrder').serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]');
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Sending Order...", true);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxxxx",
            data: {code: theForm},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){

                alert(result);                      
            }
        })
```

What I am getting back is not an array but a string. I juist wish to have a multi dimensional array on the server side that I can loop through.

Thanks

Comment: Just pass the result of `.serialize` as value of data: `data: $('#transferOrder').serialize()`.

Comment: I think you should not do `replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]')`, it will be done by the webserver

Comment: That doesnt seperate the input fields into arrays, it just posts the last row in the form..